# fetching mails from gmail inbox using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i am developing a website for a company, they need to extract the mail content like **from_address , subject , some contents**(mob_no,place etc) from the mail inbox and are displayed in the site(grid view). i tried to connect to **gmail with Pop3** the code is as follows

the code i used is:

```
Imports OpenPop.Pop3
Imports OpenPop.Mime
    Protected Sub Read_Emails(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim pop3Client As Pop3Client
        If (Session("Pop3Client") Is Nothing) Then
            pop3Client = New Pop3Client
            pop3Client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 110, False)
            pop3Client.Authenticate("mymail@gmail.com", "trustme")
            Session("Pop3Client") = pop3Client
        Else
            pop3Client = CType(Session("Pop3Client"), Pop3Client)
            MsgBox(pop3Client)
        End If
        Dim count As Integer = pop3Client.GetMessageCount
        Dim dtMessages As DataTable = New DataTable
        dtMessages.Columns.Add("MessageNumber")
        dtMessages.Columns.Add("From")
        dtMessages.Columns.Add("Subject")
        dtMessages.Columns.Add("DateSent")
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        Dim i As Integer = count
        Do While (i >= 1)
            Dim message As Message = pop3Client.GetMessage(i)
            dtMessages.Rows.Add()
            dtMessages.Rows((dtMessages.Rows.Count - 1))("MessageNumber") = i
            dtMessages.Rows((dtMessages.Rows.Count - 1))("From") = message.Headers.From.Address
            dtMessages.Rows((dtMessages.Rows.Count - 1))("Subject") = message.Headers.Subject
            dtMessages.Rows((dtMessages.Rows.Count - 1))("DateSent") = message.Headers.DateSent
            counter = counter + 1
            i = i - 1
            If counter = 5 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        gvEmails.DataSource = dtMessages
        gvEmails.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

but the problem is that: it will result in error that **"Server not found"**
[image: screen short of the error]

by referencing https://stackoverflow.com/users/1750602/khaksar-weqar **answer** i got connected with the gmail inbox, extracted some content with the above code. now i want to **extract the body content as text to my asp text box**, is their any possibility for this? positive response are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using 'http://' or 'https://', just a fleeting thought

Comment: ya i had tried "www.gmail.com" , "pop.gmail.com" , "pop3.gmail.com" , and "http://www.gmail.com" but all the time result will be the same

Comment: extracting the body content as text is a separate question, please ask it separately and we will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change bellow portion of your code:

```
pop3Client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 110, False)
pop3Client.Authenticate("mymail@gmail.com", "trustme")
```

Into :

```
pop3Client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, True)
pop3Client.Authenticate("mymail@gmail.com", "trustme", AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword)
```